[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object
I'm keep getting this error on a component that I am designing and I keep getting this error. I check the response object coming back from the endpoint REST call and it is valid JSON - it's driving me nuts
Here is my code...
Server.vue
        <v-autocomplete
          v-model="selectedDatabase"
          :items="databases"
          label="Select a database"
          outlined
          :disabled="buttonDisable"
        />
      </v-flex>
      
  computed: {
    ...
    databases: function () {
      return this.$store.state.databaseData
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // get database in the select
    loadDatabases (serverName) {
      this.clearAllTables()
      this.selectedDatabase = ''
      this.$store.commit('clearErrors')
      this.$store.dispatch('loadDatabases', {serverName})
    },

Store.js
  mutations: {
  ...
    // fetch databases
    fetchDatabaseData(state, data) {
      state.databaseData = data;
    },
  actions: {
    // load EDM database
    loadDatabases({commit}, serverName) {
      return edm_reporter_service.fetchDatabases(serverName).then((response) => {
        commit('fetchDatabaseData', response)
      })
    },

Endpoint service
      fetchDatabases (server_name) {
        store.commit('fetchDatabaseData', [])
        const url = `/servers/${server_name.serverName}/edms`
        return this.handleAPICall(API.get(url))
          .then(function (response) {
            store.commit('fetchDatabaseData', response.data)
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error)
          })
      },

My returned JSON object looks like this---
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "E24_AAD_CBT16843_CAT_900000001_v23"
        },
        {
            "name": "E24_AAD_CBT16843_CAT_upd_900000001_v23"
        },
        {
            "name": "E24_AAD_CBT2531_CAT_800_v23"
        },
        {
            "name": "E24_AAD_CBT2531_CAT_upd_800_v23"
        },
        {
            "name": "E24_AAD_CBT9942_CAm_CAT_801_v23"
        },
        {
            "name": "E24_AAD_CBT9942_CB_CAT_801_v23"
        },
        {
            "name": "E24_AAD_CBT9942_MX_CAT_801_v23"
        },
        {
            "name": "E24_AAD_CBT9942_SAm_CAT_801_v23"
        }
     ]
}

I know I've missing something but for the life of my I don't know what it is.
TIA,
Frustrated

"My returned JSON object" - where do you log it? You have commit('fetchDatabaseData in two different places. In one place "response" is commited and in other "response.data". response === undefined in loadDatabases because fetchDatabases returns nothing from a promise. It's unknown what handleAPICall does and what "response" exactly is. If it's something like axios and server response contains "data" field then it should have been response.data.data, not response.data.

@EstusFlask - I got rid of the first fetchDatabaseDate (I was using it to clear the array first) and changed response.data to response.data.data. I am using axios
handleAPICall is a method that sets up the api call
handleAPICall (call) {
    return call.catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
      throw error
    })

I'll let you know what happens

I was able to get it working by refactoring the endpoint call to and letting the store handle the commit - handling it this way solved my problem
        const url = `/servers/${server_name.serverName}/edms`
        return this.handleAPICall(API.get(url))
          .then(response => response.data.data)
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error)
          })

